# Power-law distribution for scale-free newtork

Tags: power-law, social-network

I am studying social network analysis for air travel, and now I am focusing my attention on the power law distribution, $P(k)=ck^{-r}$. I'm trying to estimate $r$ and $c$ with rstudio. [`r=2.913` & `c=0.4377`]
The original file is [here](http://file.scirp.org/Html/1-9201637_47235.htm).

Degree of node k [Degree]
Frequency [Freq]
Degree of Probability [Pk]

```
Degree <- c(78,34,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
Freq <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,7,8,6,5,3,3,5,2,2,3,4,51)
Pk <- Freq/(sum(Freq))
```

How I can estimate c and r?

Comment: The PoweRlaw package will help you out. Check out this documentation: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3492.pdf

Also keep in mind that actual power laws are considerably rarer than most people think. What looks like a power law for the first few values generally has completely different tail behavior.